# How would you go about running a java program perpetually without having to keep your personal computer running all the time?

Tags: java, database, firebase, server, hosting

I have very little background in programming, so forgive me if I don't have all the jargon correct in my question. I am currently in the process of developing a weather condition sensor that senses the weather conditions, and can be fetched via SMS to/from the sensor. Once that data is received, it would update information in a Firebase Database that is accessed from an app.

I currently have a Java program that is able to send and receive the SMS and upload that information into the Firebase Database, but the only problem I am running into is that the information is only updated so long as my computer is running the Java program.

How would I go about essentially running that Java program off a server, so that it would run regardless of whether my PC is running or not? I am looking for a free (or cheap) option that would allow me to continue testing and developing this product. Any suggestions and guidance is much appreciated!

Comment: How do you expect to run a program on a machine that is switched off? You can run the code on a machine that runs continuously with min downtime (a dedicated server, cloud probably) and then get and retrieve data from there

Comment: I think what you're asking is how do you take the data from the sensor and upload it directly to Firebase (the 'server'). Is that correct?

Comment: @Prashant I am looking for a service that would be able to run my code continuously so that I don't have to have the code running on my PC.

Comment: @Jay I mean, that directly uploading it to Firebase would work, except the way that the data is received from the sensor is via SMS. So I need to have a program that calls for an SMS every n minutes to update the data in the database.

Comment: This is a pretty broad question - what it appears you're looking for is a hosted server that can receive and process sms messages from your sensor? There are a lot of companies that provide hosted servers running java so some research may reveal a variety of options. Optionally a Raspberry Pi has a very strong following and can probably do what you want directly to Firebase.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SO.

For your problem, I recommend either getting a Raspberry Pi to host a small local machine, or possibly renting a VPS. A VPS is a "virtual private server" that you can have stay on 24/7. IONOS in my experience is a very good VPS hosing provider, however, having a Pi with you may help solve this problem in the future.

[Raspberry Pi 3 Model B+](https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/raspberry-pi-3-model-b-plus/)
[IONOS VPS](https://www.ionos.com/servers/vps)

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the quick response and direction! Upon looking into it more, both look like they would do what I need it to do!

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked heroku? 
It allows us to have 1 app freely deployed.